# Upvote questions from the Close review queue when marking as duplicate

Tags: feature-request, review

When using the review queue, I'd like to be able to upvote the question and/or answer that is the duplicate of the one being closed.

After reviewing the possible duplicate and finding that

1. it is in fact a duplicate
2. it is well written
3. the accepted/upvoted answer is suitable

then it makes sense to also upvote these, passing along credit where credit is due and making them more likely to appear in future search results. The only way to do this currently is to open the duplicate in a new browser tab/window.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

When you are reviewing close votes you're supposed to be looking at whether the question in question should be closed or not. You aren't supposed to be worrying about votes, flagging/upticking comments, and you aren't supposed to be *that* worried about editing.  You're there to either close the question or leave it open, anything else distracts from what you're there for.

I've never found opening the question in a new tab to be troublesome, but then I have a middle mouse button on my touchpad ;)

As a note, you can either:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> to open a link (in this case the question's title) in a new tab, or
2. Middle click will also open a link in a new tab.

You can then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch between tabs in a browser, upvote the question and then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to close the tab.

Comment: I understand that the focus is on closing, but is it that distracting to have the upvote button there? And the benefits would outweight the negative, in my opinion.

Comment: Not just the focus but the purpose of Close Review is to review questions that have been marked for closure.  The upvote button is for upvoting.  Two separate tools.  Is there a link button for which to open question in new tab/window like in other review sections?  Perhaps viewing question outwith review queue is the preferred way to upvote!?