# Users shouldn't have to make new accounts because they can't ask new questions anymore because of downvotes

Tags: discussion

The lost ability to ask questions is very discouraging for new users and makes them think badly of this website.Often they get downvoted by misunderstanding.They also improve their questions and/or answers to others but the downvote stays.Sometimes new users get downvotes even for mentioning they use a specific product brand from so called "fanboys"

Comment: Have you deleted any questions?

Comment: Obligatory reading, http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8533/what-should-i-do-now-that-i-cant-ask-more-questions, but in summary, no, you shouldn't.

Comment: BTW, are you question baned?

Comment: The summary is that they mostly get downvoted when they shouldn't or don't really have to and if the downvote rarely is justified their improvement is ignored and downvoted more by more users not even reading your post or trying to understand you they just read someone's wrong reason for downvoting.

Comment: @Braiam Im writing using examples of what happened to Me. I was very offended by the unjustified downvoting

Comment: This is getting no where. If you don't want to be constructive why post? Rants like this aren't appreciated.

Comment: @Seth my construction has been drawn.Now Im trying to pass the blueprint ot you.

Answer (score 4):

> The summary is that they mostly get downvoted when they shouldn't

Really? I [believe that we are not voting enough](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8373/whats-wrong-ask-ubuntu-low-voter-count), up and down. So, if some post moved the community disagreement with it (either because is wrong or impossible of understand) is a good thing that the community was shaken to certain extent.

> Im writing using examples of what happened to Me. I was very offended by the unjustified downvoting.

Well, if you want to take downvotes personal that's your *personal problem*. Downvotes has been justified in the site as "This answer is not helpful" or "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". So, instead of asking people to explain their *downvotes* sit yourself and think: what could I improve or my post is lacking to prevent more downvotes?. That is the most constructive behavior, instead of coming to Meta without a proper example of what downvotes you disagree with.

BTW, for your lack of research I downvoted your meta Q. There are figuratively, thousands of posts in meta about downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Not from me.

I have difficulty understanding how someone gets to the point of not being able to ask new questions when they ask good questions.  I've never had this happen.

I have also had a mod ask me at one point or another why I was mass deleting questions/answers.  I was cleaning out my zero queue.  So, it was self motivated site cleanup.  Still, it got a question, because I had other good answers and questions.

I just can't understand how someone can use the site well and still be in this situation.

Comment: One of my examples is I wrote Windows in title next to Ubuntu and got downvotes straight away.I asked why and got answer this is off topic.No one even read what I actually wrote! I only mentioned Windows as maybe it could fix a Ubuntu issue I had.

Comment: How do you know no one read what you wrote? You don't!

Comment: @Seth clearly they didn't or they didn't care what Ive wrote.I bet they thought let's downvote!That loser uses Windows!

Comment: @user251046 I've never seen that happen. Got a link?

Comment: Come talk about it in chat if you have an issue: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room ...  Whining here in comments is not productive.  A link would also be helpful.