# What should I do now that I can't ask more questions?

Tags: support, asking-questions, faq-proposed, post-ban

Do not repost the question you were about to ask until you have

### [READ EVERYTHING WE ARE ABOUT TO TELL YOU](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/8534/169736).

While trying to ask a question, one could get:

> We are no longer accepting questions from this account. See [the Help Center](https://askubuntu.com/help/question-bans) to learn more.

Likewise, for answers:

> We are no longer accepting answers from this account. See [the Help Center](https://askubuntu.com/help/answer-bans) to learn more.

- Why am I getting this message?
- Are deleted posts taken into account too?
- Is a question/answer ban the same as a suspension?
- How do I avoid getting a question ban?
- How long do I have to wait before I can post again? What can I do to release the ban? How can I reactivate my account?
- Can I simply create a new account?
- I'll just ask on Super User or Unix and Linux, and they'll migrate my question to the correct site!

> The [Help Center](https://askubuntu.com/help) contains more information about [question bans](https://askubuntu.com/help/question-bans) and [answer bans](https://askubuntu.com/help/answer-bans).

Comment: [Copied shamelessly from MSO guide](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/213575) with clever modifications for AU.

Comment: Why is it necessary to copy questions and answers directly from MSO?

Comment: @minerz029 because they are templates for our own... as you can see is not a carbon copy. Links are changed to our own discussion and help pages. Also, most don't read MSO nor search outside the meta.

Comment: @minerz029 Also because we can't close questions as a duplicate of question on another site. We need a post that addresses all the issues about question/answer bans. Why not just copy one that already exists?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Why am I getting this message?

As stated in the [about](https://askubuntu.com/about) links on every page, Stack Exchange is a network of *question and answer sites*, not help forums. This implies that all posts are expected to have some value for later visitors too. To enforce that, and to prevent [help vampires](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/) making the answerers turn away from the communities, low-quality questions and answers are blocked. This includes posts from:

- users who can't be bothered to form sentences
- users who don't do the most basic kinds of research themselves
- users who barely even explain what it is they are trying to do

An [automatic filter](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7194/quality-blocks-enabled-for-questions) is in place to ban questions and/or answers from IP addresses or accounts with a history of *extremely* poor posts.

To avoid bypassing the filter its internal rules are a secret, but it is partly based on downvotes cast by other members of the communities. If the other members of the site consistently give your posts a low ranking, you should try to identify the reason(s) for this.

Once you have posted too many poorly-received questions or answers, you will be banned from posting more, and you will see the error message.

### Are deleted posts taken into account too?

Yes, deleted questions (if [less than 30 days old when deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91956/i-apparently-got-question-banned-for-deleting-some-of-my-old-zero-upvoted-quest/97720#97720)) and [deleted answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105116/sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-answers-from-this-account/105119#105119) count towards an automatic ban.

It's not a problem to have deleted posts. But if a large percentage of your posts are deleted by yourself or the community, then apparently they are not suitable for the site. Posting them consumes time from users who read them, edit them, or [respond to them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74466/does-systematic-self-deleting-need-to-be-prevented/74471#74471). Therefore deleted posts [have](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86982/should-i-avoid-deleting-my-questions/87029#87029) an effect on the filter, among many other factors.

Beware that an account might very well have many deleted posts, including [auto-deleted old low-score questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year), all of which are only visible to moderators.

### Is a question/answer ban the same as a suspension?

No, a suspension is a manual, [temporary penalty](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) during which a user cannot ask questions, nor post answers. All other privileges, including commenting and voting, are also revoked by temporarily setting the reputation to 1. Such suspension is publicly visible to other users.

A post ban is enforced automatically, and only prevents posting questions or answers. It is invisible to others.

### How do I avoid getting a question ban?

[Read the pages in the Help Center](https://askubuntu.com/help), particularly those [about asking](https://askubuntu.com/help/asking) and [the Stack Exchange model](https://askubuntu.com/help/stackexchange). Investigate and search before you ask. Put some effort in your questions.

All questions are expected to have some value for later visitors too. So if *many* of your questions do not get any answer, are downvoted, closed, or deleted by yourself or the community, then apparently they did not meet the required quality. Be sure to understand why that happens, and learn from that. Don't simply repost the same question again.

If you're not sure what qualifies as a "good question", there are some hints and tips available:

- [How to Ask](https://askubuntu.com/questions/how-to-ask) from the Ask Ubuntu Help Center
- [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) by Jon Skeet
- [How to Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) by Eric S. Raymond
- [Getting Answers](http://www.mikeash.com/getting_answers.html) by Mike Ash

To learn about formatting:

- [Formatting help](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help)
- [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)
- Try for yourself in [the formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

### How long do I have to wait before I can post again? What can I do to release the ban? How can I reactivate my account?

Automatic bans never expire or "time out." This means that you cannot simply wait for a certain amount of time. If you do not take action, you will never be allowed to post again. **The only way for the ban to be lifted is by contributing positively to the site in other ways**.

Moderators cannot lift the ban.

**Before you do anything else, *fix your existing posts!*** As noted above, down-votes cast by the rest of the community factor into the ban - so the single best thing you can do to get it lifted is to address any objections raised by others. Were your past questions unclear? Did they fail to show any effort on your part? Poorly worded, titled, formatted, and overly long or short? **Then fix them!**

Note the emphasis on fixing. **Do not delete your posts.** As explained above, deleted questions (if less than 30 days old when deleted) do still count towards the question ban. Deleting your posts does not help to lift the ban. Only fixing does! Under some conditions [you can see a list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13193/how-do-i-find-questions-or-answers-that-ive-deleted/13203#13203) of your own deleted questions and answers.

If you are banned from asking questions, then writing a few quality answers that get upvoted [might](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68884/why-i-cant-ask-questions/68885#68885) enable you to ask questions again. But as the internals of the filter are secret, there is no way to know for sure.

If you really, *really* think the ban is an error, then email the team directly using the "contact us" link provided at the bottom of every page. But note that reactivation of banned accounts [is not a high priority](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62373/better-explanation-when-account-is-blocked/62374#62374).

### Can I simply create a new account?

No. The automatic ban is at [a lower level than account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72180/clarify-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this-account-error/76167#comment-174366).

### I'll just ask somewhere else on the SE network, and they'll migrate my question to the correct site!

Migrations are [not possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102293/block-migration-if-user-is-suspended-question-blocked-at-destination) if your account is banned from asking questions on the destination site. The question will simply be closed as off topic, but not migrated.

### My account is in good standing. Why am I still blocked?

The ban also takes in account the IP address. If you browse from a shared computer, or from a location that gives the same IP address to many end users, it's enough that another user who was banned or triggers the ban, will affect everyone else accessing from the same location.

To help rectify this, browse from a different location.