# It's been more than 2 months and I am still blocked from being able to ask Questions

Tags: support

Okey , I accept there may have been questions which were down voted but I have been trying my level best to re-gain the reputations Infact I have 120 reputations now. I really miss askubuntu.

Here is my [profile link](https://askubuntu.com/users/279276/yask) and some screenshots.
[image]

[image]

Comment: You probably have deleted questions you cant see. I will look into it later and see. We cannot lift the ban manually.

Comment: Yes I remember deleting a question but being a new user I did't know that it would lead to this.
Anything I can do to get back the `asking` feature?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What should I do now that I can't ask more questions?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8533/what-should-i-do-now-that-i-cant-ask-more-questions)

Comment: @Braiam: This is really scary: I always leave comments to improve OR delete user's answers before I vote for deletion (some really dodgy examples excluded). Should I stop this (bad?) behaviour and just vote for deletion?  What if I was mistaken?  Does deleting my vote for deletion reverse my vote?  :/

Comment: @Fabby huh? I don't follow...

Comment: @Braiam I've read the entire http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8533/what-should-i-do-now-that-i-cant-ask-more-questions and seeing that deleted answers for the above user count to him not being able to post, am I ensuring other users will have such a problem as well in the future? (worried)

Comment: @Fabby No, what you are doing is fine. Votes count more than simply deleted posts and if they don't delete it themselves someone else will do it anyway.

Comment: @Seth:  Whew!  Thanks!

Comment: Damn it! I wish I knew about those threats before.

Comment: @yask I believe the system has been greatly improved since you were banned, there are now a lot more warnings and it is harder to get banned outright.

Comment: They should make an exception in my case.I am new to linux and in this situation where people suggest the only way out is giving good answers, I feel as if this will never get lifted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 6 deleted questions, many of which have downvotes. These questions all appear to be either **primarily opinion based** or **too broad** so I don't believe undeleting them will accomplish much because you would not be able to edit them into good questions without completely changing their meaning.

Thus the only way to work out of the ban is to answer more questions *with better answers*. Don't go blazing away with low quality ones, take the time to test them and be sure they work, write them well, etc.

I'm afraid that is all the help I can give you.

Comment: I am not an expert on Ubuntu , Infact I am new to it.
Answering good quality question won't be my piece of cake.
I have a feeling that this ban may never get lifted.Since I have already tried answering as much as possible from my side for more than 2 months.

Comment: @yask Looks like your last answer lifted the ban, you should be able to ask questions again. Make sure you take the time to ask a good, well written on though, the system will probably have you on a short leash for a bit (i.e. one or two bad questions will get you blocked again)

Comment: Wow! it is finally lifted after such a long time! Thank you guys for your suggestions!