# Why was I banned from asking questions?

Tags: support

I was banned from asking questions, but I don't know why!

Who is the person who decides these things?

How can I learn if you don't let me ask the things I don't know (even if they are too much boring to someone)?

How can I get the right to ask questions again?

Comment: I think the computer decides, you do have a lot of questions, try going through them and updating/editing/responding to comments ect.

Comment: A robot decides who is banned but are you banned or did it say`you reached your question limit`? You have a lot of questions but they are not badly received, it seems more likely you reached your current limit.

Comment: No. It says I banned. Whatever, I didn't know about the questions number limit. What can I do about this? ???

Comment: What is the message exactly? It might also be worth going to chat and talking to a mod, I have seen both oli and seth around in the last hour or so.

Comment: The message changed. Now I see you were right: It is about the number of questions limitation. I couldn't see help about that.

Comment: You should ask about that in chat, they will be able to explain the limits to you and tell you when you can ask again.

Comment: According to Seth the user was banned from asking questions and they didn't reach the daily threshold. So it's a duplicate of this one: http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8533/380067

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All the information you need to know about the automatic ban system is outlined in the post linked in the message you receive: [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

You aren't blocked because your questions are "too boring", you are blocked because your questions are not meeting our quality standards. I suggest you take a look through [the help article on writing a good question.](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) This ban didn't happen suddently either, you were warned 7 times in December and 6 in January that the questions you were asking weren't being well received, along with guidance on how to ask better questions.